# How to countercheck a Boost Error Code appropriately?

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, boost-asio

I have a callback function which is bound to a `boost::asio::deadline_timer`. Now the function is called when the timer is cancelled or it expires. Since I need to distinguish between this two cases I need to check the passed Error code. The basic code would be like this:

```
void CameraCommand::handleTimeout(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << "\nError: " << error.message() << "\n";
    return;
}
```

Now when the Handler is called because the timer expired the error code is `Success`, when the timer is cancelled the error code is `Operation canceled`.

Now my question would be, how to appropriately check what happened?

Suggestion 1:

```
if( error.message() == "Success" )
{
     // Timer expired
}
else
{
     // Timer cancelled
}
```

Suggestion 2:

```
if( error.value() == 0 )
{
     // Timer expired
}
else
{
     // Timer cancelled
}
```

Now my question is - is there any way to compare the error byitself and not by value or by string? Something like ( this is made up now )

```
if ( error == boost::system::error::types::success )
```

Because what I don't like about the first suggestion is that I need to create a string just for check, which is kinda unnecessary in my opinion. The second way has the disadvantge that I need to look up all the error codes if I want to check for something other?
So are there any enums or ways to check for the error or do I have one of the two suggested ways?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/system/error_code.hpp), you can use the enum values:

```
switch( error.value() )
{
    case boost::system::errc::success:
    {
    }
    break;

    case boost::system::errc::operation_canceled:
    {
      // Timer cancelled
    }
    break;

    default:
    {
       // Assert unexpected case
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I might have got this wrong. This says we should be comparing error_codes to error_conditions and should not use the value() for comparisons. http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-2.html

Comment: This is incorrect. boost error_code has categories and values. The same value can exist in more than one category. You must check both.

Answer (score 16):

You can just use a boolean cast:

```
if ( error )
{ 
    // Timer has been cancelled - or some other error. If you just want information
    // about the error then you can output the message() of the error.
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

`boost::error_code` has a boolean operator for this, have a look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html#Class-error_code

Comment: Okay, this would be appropriate for this particular problem, since I just want to determine if it has been cancelled or just expired, what would mean `if(!error)`, but how to check for a particular error?

Comment: One thing to note is that each part of BOOST will have its own set of error codes. Check out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html

Comment: IMHO `if (error.value() != boost::system::errc::success)` is more precise, more readable and **does not depend on the boolean operator override implementation** and therefore is programmed to an interface, not an implementation.

Comment: @MartinMeeser Thanks for the important point. `if (error.value() != boost::system::errc::success)` means it is an error? Or does it mean its not a an error?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a default constructed error_code:

```
if( error == boost::system::error_code() )
```